# How can I obtain crash logs for Mobile Safari in the iOS Simulator?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, mobile-safari

If Mobile Safari crashes in the iOS Simulator, where can the crash logs be found?

(Apple will want these attached to your bug reports.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for files named `MobileSafari_*.crash` in `~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/`.

(Execute `open ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/` in Terminal, then sort by date modified.)